# Why this tbb program cannot compile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, queue, tbb

I install the threading building blocks(http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=174)  in centos in directory /home/is_admin/tbb40_233oss/

This is my code:

```
#include "tbb/concurrent_queue.h" 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
using namespace tbb; 
int main() { 
    concurrent_queue<int> queue; 
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i ) 
        queue.push(i); 
    for( concurrent_queue<int>::const_iterator i(queue.begin()); 
i!=queue.end(); ++i ) 
        cout << *i << " "; 
    cout << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

I compile the code using this command:

```
g++ test_concurrent_queue.cpp -I/home/is_admin/tbb40_233od/linux_intel64_gcc_cc4.1.2_libc2.5_kernel2.6.18_release -ltbb -o tcq
```

but it gives this error:

```
class tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> > has no member named begin

class tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> > has no member named end
```

I cann't find out why? Anybody have tbb experience can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

The documentation you used is outdated and no longer works with `concurrent_queue`. The rest of my answer still stands.

---

Because `concurrent_queue` has no `begin` or `end` method:
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00134.html

There is an `unsafe_begin` and an `unsafe_end` method, named that way because you should only use them if your queue isn't being used by more than one thread (that is, they are *unsafe* to use in a multithreaded environment).

The general way to run through a queue is to pop elements until it's empty:

```
int i;
while(queue.try_pop(i)) // as long as you can pop, pop.
    cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to use the concurrent_bounded_queue?The code is the sample code of threadingbuildingblocks.org http://cache-www.intel.com/cd/00/00/30/11/301114_301114.pdf#page=61

Comment: Hm, I might have missed something. The answer I gave was for `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue`, which is what your compiler thinks `concurrent_queue` refers to. Looks like there's another `concurrent_queue` class with a different interface.

Comment: @Greper: The document you linked to is from 2007. There is newer documentation [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php).

Comment: @Jesse Yeah, that he used outdated documentation was my best guess.